# Linking rows/columns in Kendo Grid with different hper links

Tags: jquery-ui, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo Grid to show my search results.
Below is the code for Kendo Grid.

**jQuery**

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: {
    data: gridData,
    schema: {
      data: "Results"
    },
    pageSize: 20
  },
  height: 550,
  sortable : true,
  pageable: {
    refresh: true,
    pageSizes: true,
    buttonCount: 5
  },
  columns: gridData.viewFields
});
$("#grid").kendoGrid('refresh');
```

I am adding data dynamically to gridData.viewFields. 
Now i am trying to make rows clickable and navigate to display forms of items dynamically. I am struck here for a while. Any contribution is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll need to configure the grid to allow the row selection by setting the value for the `selectable` property:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    selectable: "row"
    //Other configuration value...
});
```

Then, you have to listen to the `change` event that will be triggered when the user will change the grid selection:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    //Other configuration value...
    change: function() {
        var selectedRow = this.select();
        //Insert your dynamic for logic here and user selectedRow to get the selected data
    }
});
```

Comment: Done, Thank you again